# What does the phrase 'to brain toss' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I have already done some research and I found out that **'to toss'** also has a slang meaning and can be considered similar to the word **'to f*ck'**. Is that right?

I heard this phrase in a video by 'Epic Rap Battles Of History' on YouTube. Darth Vader battles Adolf Hitler and says the following: “I strike back hard against a nazi, **brain toss** your ass in the air, yahtzee!“

Does it, on the one hand, mean the same as **'brain fuck your ass'** and at the same time refer to tossing a dice, as he says **'yahtzee'** at the end? To me it sounds like this indicates him tossing Hitler (like you would toss a dice) - he basically **f*cks** him (as you would say it in a rap battle).

I am still a bit confused about the phrase **brain toss** and why he would brain toss him **in the air**.

**Does 'to toss' mean the same as 'to f*ck' and if not, what is the meaning of this phrase in the given context?**

*(Already answered satisfactorily)*

Comment: You're making a fundamental mistake if you are trying to fit lyrics (in any popular music genre, not just rap) to some sort of standard of sense. Lyrics very often are intended to mean just what the reader wants them to mean: the author usually has much more on their mind (rhythm, sound, scansion, percussive effect, etc.) than making sure that the lyric makes logical or even grammatical sense. Just decide for yourself what it means and stick to that.

Comment: I think what you say about rhythm and so on is right, but there are a lot of songs that really want to express a certain message, not just anything the reader can understand in this or in that way. If you take a look at other parts of this particular 'battle' you will find that there are many lyrics that are perfectly clear to understand in their meaning. Mostly it even makes grammatical and, of course, logical sense. And this is the kind of stuff that is just genius, in this case the combining of true facts from history, rhythm, rhyme, grammatics and the logical sense.

Comment: Let me add that especially in rap the words are the most important thing (at least if you take it seriously). Therefore, I would partly even disagree with you, as the lyrics are definitely meant to make sense and (depending on the individual song) want to express a certain, specific message. I know what you mean, though.

Comment: "To toss" as a slang meaning "to f*ck" is not true in American English (the Epic Rap Battles creator is an American). American readers might recognize the phrase with that meaning in context, but it's not a phrase that Americans use. Mcalex's answer is correct; Darth Vader is referring to the his telekinetic powers in the song -- to physically throw Hitler across the room with his mind.

Comment: If you've already accepted an answer, why do you want it reopened?

Comment: I just think that an [on hold] behind the question does not look good, it kind of bothers me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your reasoning is logical, I don't think this is a phrase/cliche, but just words strung together.

Darth Vader knows jedi mind tricks.  These include controlling people physically using his mental powers.  In this vein, I think 'brain toss' is very literally using his mind to physically move Hitler - probably the jedi trick 'force repulse' or 'force push' as described [on the star wars wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_Repulse).